# Upon posting Edit(), return Details.cshtml of edited item rather than Index.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, crud

In an ASP.NET MVC app, say you have a simple model class `Blog` and you are updating an entry with an edit action.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Title")] Blog blog)
{
    // controller logic here
    return View(blog);
}
```

This returns the (default-named) `Index.cshtml` view of `Blog`. How would you get this to return the `Details.cshtml` view of the same `Blog` item that was edited? I feel like this is a simple change but I haven't been able to find anything answering this and I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: AFAIK this should return to the Edit view not to the Index one. Something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return Detail view by blog Model

```cs
return View("Detail",blog);
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed to provide the full path in this instance, e.g., `return View("~/Views/Blogs/Details.cshtml", blog)`.

Comment: Glad I could help. a better way is use the `nameof` to prevent syntax error. for example `return View(nameof(Details),blog);`

Answer (score 1):

If your Detail.cshtml has a GET action in the controller, to be safer you can also use a reflection:

```
return View(nameof(Detail),blog);
```

Please keep in mind that in such a case the `Details.cshtml` must use the same model object as you are trying to return e.g. `@model MyApp.Models.Blog`

Comment: Thanks for that, especially the last point. I'm getting an internal server error because while it seems to route correctly, my `Details.cshtml` view invokes a navigation property of `Blog`, so I get a null reference exception "object reference not set to an instance of an object".